# CSS3 Transitions with opacity not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I am having a problem with chaining of transitions when I try to transition opacity. Otherwise its working fine. Without opacity, the console.log displays:

```
Transition no 1 started at: 1523817891340
Transition no 1 ended at: 1523817893361
Transition no 2 started at: 1523817893363
Transition no 2 ended at: 1523817895358
```

This is correct (approximate).

Now if I uncomment the opacity transitioning, I get the following output, which is obviously wrong:

```
Transition no 1 started at: 1523818593850
Transition no 1 ended at: 1523818595856
Transition no 2 started at: 1523818595857
Transition no 2 ended at: 1523818595859
Transition no 2 ended at: 1523818597854
Transition no 2 ended at: 1523818597855
```

Inexplicable! Notice that the second transition run for very short duration and that triggers other issues!

```
    ...
    <style>
        .tryDiv {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background: red;
            display : block;
        }
    </style>
     ...
    <div class="tryDiv" ></div>
    ...
$(document).ready(function() {
  countM=1;

  /**** SET TRANSITION-END EVENT HANDLER *****/
  $('.tryDiv').on('webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd transitionEnd', function() {
     console.log("Transition no " + (countM-1) + " ended at: " + new Date().getTime());
     if (countM<=2) _startTransition();
   });

   function _startTransition() {
      switch (countM) {
       case 1: var transitionVal = 'opacity 2s, transform 2s, -webkit-transform 2s';
               var css = {//opacity: 0.5, 
                 transform: 'scale(.5)','-webkit-transform': 'scale(.5)'};
                  break;
          case 2: var transitionVal = 'opacity 2s, transform 2s, -webkit-transform 2s';
                  var css = { //opacity: 1,
                     transform:'scale(1)','-webkit-transform': 'scale(1)'};
                  break;
      }

      $('.tryDiv').css('-ms-transition', transitionVal);
      $('.tryDiv').css('-webkit-transition', transitionVal);
      $('.tryDiv').css('-transition', transitionVal);
      console.log("Transition no " + countM + " started at: " + new Date().getTime());
      $('.tryDiv').css(css);
      ++countM;

   };
   /*** STARTS HERE BY EXECUTING FIRST TRANSITION ***/
   _startTransition();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, when you apply `transition` to more than 1 rule, you'll get *n* "ending" logs at approximately the same time; in your case - 2 seconds after animation starts (where *n* is the amount of rules to which `transition` is applied). This happens because transitions for different css rules are considered to be different transition events.

The reason why you get the "second" "ending" log slightly after first "starting" log is because it actually corresponds the first animation, but your event handler uses the variable value from the closure so it outputs `2` instead of `1` there.

In order to avoid this, you can call your function that triggers animation again by using `setTimeout` with the duration of animation (`2`s or `2000`ms), with a little space for the error (I made it `2030`ms, for example).
Here is [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/4w2yyxuL/2/) (look at the console output there).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did not know that it fires multiple events for the same **set of transitions** That explains a lot. But I want to avoid using setTimeout for firing the next animation (set of transitions) and rather be sure that the previous  one has completed before firing the next. Guess I will have to keep some sort of flag, possibly and array of objects for each animation, to avoid restarting the same set. Right? This is part of a bigger generalized framework. The example given was a simplified one to explain the problem. Thanks. Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: If you have any solution  or recommendations, please comment. Of course, you have answered the main question asked.